# NPSP URL Buttons don't display in Lightning

Tags: related-list, url, action, npsp

I'm using the latest version of the NPSP and noticed that URL buttons are no longer supported for custom actions on related lists when in Lightning mode. This causes an issue because the org I'm working with makes extensive use of single donations, yet I have no way to access it without the custom buttons for Donations/Opportunity.

This only way I've found seems to be creating a VF page that acts as a URL builder and redirect.
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BWr4IAG

Is this the current method for getting this behavior to work or does the NPSP have a work around for this already built?

Comment: The Salesforce.org team is currently working on Lightning-izing the NPSP. Lately, they've been saying they expect NPSP to be "production ready" in Lightning after the Summer release. Check out the Lightning group on the Power of Us Hub to learn more!

Comment: That's kinda what I was hoping to hear. I wanted to start these customers on Lightning and avoid training twice, but what can you do...

Comment: Also, according to the release notes, URL buttons will be supported in Lightning in the Spring '16 release.